# A doubt on the definition of p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, inference

The p-value is the probability, under the assumption of the null hypothesis $H_0$, of obtaining a result equal to or more extreme than what was observed at given data.

This means, if I were to repeat my experiment an infinite number of times, the proportion of times that my observed data would give results equal or more extreme, under $H_0$, would be equal to the p-value.

My doubt is the meaning of the «under $H_0$» or «under the assumption of the null hypothesis $H_0$» parts. What do they mean? Only if $H_0$ is true, will the p-value magnitude have some importance in assessing whether the results obtained at this given data study provide evidence against or for $H_0$? If I were to get a low p-value, while $H_0$ was true, what could I conclude? \footnote{To me this seems possible to happen. If we simulate a linear DGP, with the usual assumptions to make sure OLS is BLUE, and if the error terms had great variance, then at an experiment I could some estimates completely different from the DGP, making the p-value very low, no?} What would mean to calculate $P(T(\mathbf{X})\geq T_0)$ when $\theta\in \Theta_1$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me that your second paragraph is true: the $p$-value is a function of your sample. So, the $p$ value would therefore change from one sample to the next in your "infinite experiment" and likely the mean of those $p$ values would center on 0.5 (assuming your H$_{0}$ was of the "no effect"/"no difference" type).

Comment: Not only if the null is true will *p* have any importance, but only then is it an accurate description of the probability of obtaining results as least as extreme. The null hypothetical scenario is useful as a simple basis for comparison in a very wide variety of applications where it is not true. If the null is true, you're just as likely to calculate a low *p* value as a high one. When the null is true (and other elements of analysis are handled properly), *p* values are distributed uniformly across replications.

Comment: If only p-values would adhere to the likelihood principle ...

Comment: @NickStauner could you point me in the direction of a paper, or book that might explain in more detail what you wrote? Thanks.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer your question directly, I think this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKA4w2O61Xo&index=54&list=LL4aLT03KAOjLGpgETuW47dw) helps one understand why we assume the null hypothesis is true in many experiments and other situation (largely has to do with the innocent until proven guilty concept)

Comment: The characterization of "equal or more extreme" in the penultimate line is not quite correct. The right way--as revealed by the [Neyman-Pearson Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma)--is in terms of the likelihood of $T(\mathbf{X})$ rather than in terms of its value.

Comment: @whuber It's the first time that I'm reading that the characterization of the 'extreme' results is described in terms of LR, instead $T(\mathbf{X})$. Where can I learn more about it? Can you point me to a paper/book, please? Many thanks.

Comment: @user159813 I think your video answers more to the question of why don't we accept $H_0$ but we instead fail to reject $H_0$. Assuming the $H_0$ is because it's simpler, and hence allows to find a probability distribution for the statistic more easily in some cases, I think.

Comment: For why the likelihood ratio is the relevant measure of "extreme," please follow the link I gave to the Wikipedia article on the Neyman-Pearson Lemma.  This lemma is stated and proven--to some degree--in any textbook on classical mathematical statistics.  An account from an elementary mathematical standpoint is given in Kiefer's *Introduction to Statistical Inference,* for instance.